# Python SQLite executemany() always in order?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

In Python, I'm using SQLite's executemany() function with INSERT INTO to insert stuff into a table. If I pass executemany() a list of things to add, can I rely on SQLite inserting those things from the list in order? The reason is because I'm using INTEGER PRIMARY KEY to autoincrement primary keys. For various reasons, I need to know the new auto-incremented primary key of a row around the time I add it to the table (before or after, but around that time), so it would be very convenient to simply be able to assume that the primary key will go up one for every consecutive element of the list I'm passing executemany(). I already have the highest existing primary key before I start adding stuff, so I can increment a variable to keep track of the primary key I expect executemany() to give each inserted row. Is this a sound idea, or does it presume too much?

(I guess the alternative is to use execute() one-by-one with sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(), but that's slower than using executemany() for many thousands of entries.)

Answer (score 3):

Python's `sqlite3` module executes the statement with the list values in the correct order.

Note: if the code already knows the to-be-generated ID value, then you should insert this value explicitly so that you get an error if this expectation turns out to be wrong.

Comment: Well, it'll only give me an error if I duplicate an existing primary key, not if I skip an auto-incremented one... still, good idea, thanks.